# Was the wording on each tablet sized differently?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-ki-tisa, aseres-hadibros, tablets

Was the wording on each tablet sized differently? It's said that the second tablet that contained the Commandments for man's relationship to man had larger wording so man would have no problem reading them. Is this true?

Comment: See this answer https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/13841/759

Comment: You assume the two tablets had different texts

Comment: @DoubleAA Are there any Midrashim that say that all ten were on both?

Comment: @DonielF In the [Yerushalmi](https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Shekalim.25a.1?with=all&lang=bi) referred to [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13820/shape-of-the-luchot/13841#comment266126_13841) by Double AA.