# How many stones of the Luchos were there?

Tags: aseres-hadibros

We know there were two sets of tablets that Moshe got. We know that each tablet was double-sided. How many actual side-by-side stones were there in each set? The pictures usually show there were two side-by-side stones. Is this true?
In other words when Moshe received the first set of Luchos, how many stones was he holding one or two?
Source-based answers, please.

Comment: 2x2=4 Am I missing something? @fulltimekollelguy

Comment: As in if each stone has 2 parts (as you said) and there are 2 then there were 4 stones. @fulltimekollelguy

Comment: That is what you said @fulltimekollelguy

Comment: Each tablet was more than double sided. It was six sided (like all three dimensional objects)

Comment: true, all six sides had text?

Comment: I am accepting this answer and going to pose a simlar question in hopefuly a more detailed manner

Comment: @fulltimekollelguy machloket https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/13841/759

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exodus 31:18 says that there were two tablets:
שְׁנֵי לֻחֹת הָעֵדֻת לֻחֹת אֶבֶן

Comment: Well done! אבן is singular while it says 2. So is the two referring to double sided? Were the two stones able to separate?

Comment: @fulltimekollelguy that's simply how Hebrew works. If they were made of gold, the term of the material would have also been singular. לוחות זהב, לוחות עץ, לוחות כסף, לוחות שיש. It's the same in every material. So, two tablets, both made of stone.

Comment: @fulltimekollelguy אבן isn’t singular. Just like the English “tablets of stone”.

Comment: I am accepting this answer and going to pose a simlar question in hopefuly a more detailed manner